# Regex for unsanitized data - Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have some unsanitized data which I need to split into an array using perl. Ideally, I would have a sequence of values separated by commas. In this case, I would use the following to split the data:

```
/,\s*/
```

Unfortunately this is a bit of a special case. Here is an example of the data I have:

```
Cat Bag
Dog Hair
Turkey brown Caller
Thirteen,BoyXbox
Mac
LizardDinosaur
```

The final array should be:

```
[Cat Bag, Dog Hair, Turkey brown Caller, Thirteen, Boy, Xbox, Mac, Lizard, Dinosaur]
```

As you can see, I need to split on newline characters, commas, and if there are two words next to each other with no space (eg: BoyXbox).

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know a string contains 2 words if there is no space (e.g. `without = with + out`, will you treat that as 2 words or 1 word?)

Comment: In this case words right next to each other will start with a capital letter. It would be WithOut in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a literal implementation of the requirement

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = <<END_STRING;
Cat Bag
Dog Hair
Turkey brown Caller
Thirteen,BoyXbox
Mac
LizardDinosaur
JRAinsley-McEwan Class1C
END_STRING

my @s = split/\s*[\n,]\s*|(?<=\S)(?=[A-Z])/, $s;

say join ', ', map qq{"$_"}, @s;
```

**output**

```
"Cat Bag", "Dog Hair", "Turkey brown Caller", "Thirteen", "Boy", "Xbox", "Mac", "Lizard", "Dinosaur", "J", "R", "Ainsley-", "Mc", "Ewan Class1", "C"
```